# How to identify the gradient behaviour of the image

Tags: python, opencv

In order to identify the flashlight spot/glare, I extract the white region of the image successfully but in some cases, We need to differentiate between the glare area and normal white colour places(some time our images can have a white colour background). For that, We can use the gradient pattern to identify the glare region since the gradeint follows the same pattern as it decreases from the center place to the border of the region.
I used laplacian variance but I think, It can be implemented better than using laplacian varaince. Can anyone assist me?

[image]     [image]      [image]

Comment: you could start in the center of those subimages and use LineIterator to analyse pixels to the outisde and try to find some linear or quadratic (or any other decrease of intensity). Or you could remove the plain white pixels and try to fit a 3D parabola to that area and analyse the slope parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We can find the gradient of an image by the help of Sobel and Laplacian derivatives of the image.

refer this: https://www.codespeedy.com/find-the-gradient-of-an-image-in-python/